# How to know if it not clicked on any element inside the same parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple table rows (Sample Table added).

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td valign="top">Title <span class="asterisk">*</span></td>
        <td>
        <textarea name="title" id="title" rows="2" style="width:100%" class="required show-chracter-count show-field-hint" data-fieldname="title">
        </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>Almost like the same </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am hiding/showing some hint texts by appending some html content on focus/blur event of the inputs.

```
$('.show-field-hint').on('focus', function() {
    get_hints_and_display($(this));
});

$('.show-field-hint').on('blur', function() {
    hide_hints($(this));
});

function get_hints_and_display(thisObj)
{
    var field= thisObj.data('fieldname');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pathtofile.php?field=' + field,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            if(response)
            {
                var htmlToAppend= $('<div class="hint-div" style="width:100%;clear:both;padding:10px;display:none;">' + response + '</div>');
                var parentTd = thisObj.parent('td');
                if(parentTd.find('div.hint-div').length > 0)
                    parentTd.find('div.hint-div').remove();
                parentTd.append(htmlToAppend);
                parentTd.find('div.hint-div').slideDown();
            }
        }
    })
}

function hide_hints(thisObj)
{
    var hintDiv= thisObj.siblings('div.hint-div');
    hintDiv.slideUp();
    setInterval(function(){remove_hint_div(hintDiv)}, 1000);
}
function remove_hint_div(divObj)
{
    divObj.remove();
}
```

And removing by simple `remove()` function. But I want to remove the hint part only if user clicked/blurred from the current element on/to some element outside the current row. Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: where is the js code??

Comment: please show us full code.

Comment: Added the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [focusout javascript event](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) to do this.

**Edit:**

```
$( ".myinput" ).focusout(function() {
    $( this ).parent().children( ".hint-div" ).remove();
});
```

Working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdobLn5t/).

**Edit 2**:
with the edited question, I understand it better. The key is to not use the blur or focusout. But remove any previous hints when a new input gets the focus.

```
if(parentTd.find('div.hint-div').length == 0) {
  // First remove any previously displayed hints.
  $( '.hint-div' ).each(function() {hide_hints($( this ));});
  // Add new-hint for the current box.
  parentTd.append(htmlToAppend);
  parentTd.find('div.hint-div').slideDown();
}
```

I have a working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ld4achfh/2/

Comment: I would appreciate if people voting this down would leave a comment with the reason.

Comment: For your appreciation, before I downvoted, I didn't have a single clue what you were trying to say.

Comment: My first response was indeed a one-liner and I also misunderstood the question. I have edited it since then. @PraveenKumar Thanks!

Comment: Also have some fields with tinyMCE. That would also be taken care off. :)